# Atom IDE - Keybinding

Tags: ide, key-bindings, atom-editor

I have disabled the default Atom IDE keybinding for the combination <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> (In my keymap.cson):

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-f': 'unset!'
```

How to make it to show <kbd>[</kbd> character when I click <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this, based on [this forum entry](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-create-key-binding-for-inserting-text-in-editor/21718/6):

- Open the editor's `init.coffee` script file (Menu: `Atom > Init Script...`)
- Insert the following text (make sure to use the right indentation:

  ```
  atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
    'custom:insert-bracket': ->
      atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('[')
  ```
- Save the file.
- Open the keybinding file (Menu: `Atom > Keymap...`)
- Add the following mapping (replacing yours) to call the new command:

  ```
  'atom-text-editor':
    'alt-f': 'custom:insert-bracket'
  ```
- Save the file.
- As a last step, restart Atom.

This worked for me, pressing <kbd>Alt+f</kbd> now inserts an opening bracket (which is automatically completed with a closing bracket by Atom).